# Construir uma nova coluna condicionalmente

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho um banco de dados que chamei `teste` com resultados de testes para doenças em pacientes fictícios (0=negativo, 1 = positivo e 2 = não sei). Preciso construir uma nova coluna "Infectado" nesta tabela usando condicionais de modo que a variável `Infectado` deve receber 1 se o paciente testar positivo para pelo menos uma das doenças e 0 para qualquer outro desfecho (negativo/não sei/NA). Supostamente, a variável infectado deveria terminar assim:

| HIV | HPV | Sifilis | Infectado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | NA | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

Dados:

```
teste <- data.frame(HIV = c(0, 0, NA, 2, 0, 1),
                    HPV = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0),
                    Sifilis = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Permita-me comentar: Creio que a coluna já dever ser criada no banco de dados, independentemente da resposta. A questão é criar uma condição no código de programação, que faça a seleção de qual resposta será armazenada nesta coluna: 0 ou 1.

Answer (score 3):

Uma maneira de fazer o que é desejado é utilizando a função `ifelse`. Ela irá testar se alguma das colunas `HIV`, `HPV` ou `Sifilis` possui o valor `1`. Caso possua, a coluna `Infectado` será criada com o valor `1`. Caso contrário, o valor utilizado em `Infectado` será 0.

```r
teste <- data.frame(HIV = c(0, 0, NA, 2, 0, 1),
                    HPV = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0),
                    Sifilis = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

library(tidyverse)

teste %>%
  mutate(Infectado = ifelse(HIV == 1 | HPV == 1 | Sifilis == 1, 1, 0))
#>   HIV HPV Sifilis Infectado
#> 1   0   0       0         0
#> 2   0   0       1         1
#> 3  NA  NA       1         1
#> 4   2  NA       1         1
#> 5   0  NA       2        NA
#> 6   1   0       2         1
```

Entretanto, perceba que a função `ifelse` possui uma limitação. Ela não é capaz de lidar com `NA`, como no caso do paciente 5. Por isso, utilizamos a função `replace_na` para ter um resultado como o que a pergunta pede:

```r
teste %>%
  mutate(Infectado = ifelse(HIV == 1 | HPV == 1 | Sifilis == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  replace_na(list(Infectado = 0))
#>   HIV HPV Sifilis Infectado
#> 1   0   0       0         0
#> 2   0   0       1         1
#> 3  NA  NA       1         1
#> 4   2  NA       1         1
#> 5   0  NA       2         0
#> 6   1   0       2         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Oi Marcus, estava vendo aqui que existe a função `if_else()` do dplyr que lida com os valores NA:
É possível especificar o valor que se quer quando o valor retornado for NA.

Answer (score 3):

Pode aplicar `any` às linhas ("margem 1") para ver se ao menos uma coluna corresponde à condição desejada:

```
apply(teste == 1, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Como R codifica VERDADEIRO/FALSO como 0/1, pode usar `as.integer` para armazenar no formato desejado:

```
teste$Infectado <- as.integer(apply(teste == 1, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE))

teste
#>   HIV HPV Sifilis Infectado
#> 1   0   0       0         0
#> 2   0   0       1         1
#> 3  NA  NA       1         1
#> 4   2  NA       1         1
#> 5   0  NA       2         0
#> 6   1   0       2         1
```

Ou simplesmente armazene o vetor lógico e use-o para indexar sua base de dados.

Answer (score 2):

Uma resposta com `rowSums`.

```
as.integer(rowSums(teste == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 0 1

teste$Infetado <- as.integer(rowSums(teste == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

---

### Teste comparativo

Já há várias respostas e aqui vai um teste comparativo de desempenho.

Em primeiro lugar, O código das respostas do [Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/538813/82237) e do [Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/538867/82237) é reescrito como funções.
Além disso, incluí uma função `Marcus2` com `as.integer` em vez de `ifelse` porque `as.integer` aplicado a condições lógicas é geralmente muito mais rápido que `ifelse(cond, 1, 0)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Marcus1 <- function(X){
  X %>%
    mutate(Infectado = ifelse(HIV == 1 | HPV == 1 | Sifilis == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
    replace_na(list(Infectado = 0))
}
Marcus2 <- function(X){
  X %>%
    mutate(Infectado = as.integer(HIV == 1 | HPV == 1 | Sifilis == 1)) %>%
    replace_na(list(Infectado = 0L))
}
CarlosEduardo <- function(X){
  X[["Infectado"]] <- as.integer(apply(X == 1, 1, any, na.rm = TRUE))
  X
}
Rui <- function(X){
  X[["Infectado"]] <- as.integer(rowSums(X == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
  X
}
```

Os resultados são numericamente iguais. As diferenças são:

- A classe da tabela, `"data.frame"` no caso de funções que só utilizam o R base e classe `"tibble"` no caso do `tidyverse`.
- a classe da coluna criada, que pode ser `"numeric"` ou `"integer"`, consoante os casos (função `Marcus1` e as outras funções).

Por isso as comparações são feitas com `all.equal` e com `identical`.

```
all.equal(
  Marcus1(teste) %>% as.data.frame(),
  CarlosEduardo(teste)
)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(
  Marcus1(teste) %>% as.data.frame(),
  Rui(teste)
)
#[1] TRUE

identical(
  Marcus2(teste) %>% as.data.frame(),
  CarlosEduardo(teste)
)
#[1] TRUE

identical(
  Marcus2(teste) %>% as.data.frame(),
  Rui(teste)
)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

### Agora o desempenho.

A função `testFun` testa a velocidade das funções acima para bases cada vez maiores, agrega os resultados e calcula medianas dos tempos. O valor da função é depois mostrado num gráfico.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

testFun <- function(X, n, verbose = TRUE){
  out <- lapply(seq.int(n), \(k){
    Y <- X
    for(i in seq.int(k)) Y <- rbind(Y, Y)
    if(verbose){
      msg <- sprintf("Iteração: %d, nrows: %d", k, nrow(Y))
      message(msg)
    }
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      tidyverse1 = Marcus1(Y),
      tidyverse2 = Marcus2(Y),
      apply = CarlosEduardo(Y),
      rowSums = Rui(Y)
    )
    agg <- aggregate(time ~ expr, mb, median)
    agg$nrow <- nrow(Y)
    agg
  })
  do.call(rbind, out)
}

res <- testFun(teste, 15)
g <- ggplot(res, aes(nrow, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()

g + scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  labs(x = expression("Nº de linhas da base: " * log[2] * "(n)"), 
       y = expression("Tempo: " * log[10] * "(t)")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Função"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Conclusões do teste

1. Para bases pequenas, médias e não muito grandes o R base é de longe mais rápido. Mesmo o ciclo `apply` é competitivo com o `tidyverse` e o `rowSums`, com o ciclo em linguagem C, é francamente o melhor.
2. Para bases grandes o `tidyverse` ganha vantagem e essa vantagem parece ser crescente.
3. Surpreendentemente, o `ifelse` não é muito mais lento que o `as.integer`. A diferença só é visível para bases grandes.
4. No caso do `tidyverse`, o `ifelse` é talvez mais fácil de perceber e tendo em conta a pequena diferença de tempos, não há grande vantagem em optar pelo `as.integer`.

Comment: Não percebi o voto para baixo, acho a resposta só com uma linha francamente melhor do que um teste de um problema tão simples.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui uma sugestão usando `case_when()`

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
teste %>% 
  mutate(infectado = case_when(HIV|HPV|Sifilis == 1 ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0))
```

Com `mutate` vc cria uma coluna `infectado` que será preenchida da seguinte forma:

- caso (`case_when()`) a coluna HIV *ou* HPV *ou* Sifilis (`HIV|HPV|Sifilis`):

  - for igual (`== 1`), preencher com "1" (`~ 1`),
  - para todos os outros casos (`TRUE`) preencher com "0" (`~ 0`)

Resultado:

```
  HIV HPV Sifilis infectado
1   0   0       0         0
2   0   0       1         1
3  NA  NA       1         1
4   2  NA       1         1
5   0  NA       2         0
6   1   0       2         1
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui a opção usando o `if_else()` do `dplyr`

```
teste %>% 
  mutate(infectado = if_else(condition = HIV|HPV|Sifilis == 1, 
                             true = 1,
                             false = 0,
                             missing = 0))
```

resultado:

```
  HIV HPV Sifilis infectado
1   0   0       0         0
2   0   0       1         1
3  NA  NA       1         1
4   2  NA       1         1
5   0  NA       2         0
6   1   0       2         1
>
```